# Split list of list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list with several strings and would like to have a list of string lists

**I try:**

```
phrases = ['hello how are you', 'the book is good', 'this is amazing', 'i am angry']

list_of_list = [words for phrase in phrases for words in phrase]
```

**My output:**

```
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'h', 'o', 'w', ' ', ...]
```

**Good output:**

```
[['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['the', 'book', 'is', 'good'], ['this', 'is', 'amazing'], ['i', 'am', 'angry']
```

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
>>> [phrase.split() for phrase in phrases]
[['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['the', 'book', 'is', 'good'], ['this', 'is', 'amazing'], ['i', 'am', 'angry']]
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
list_of_list = [words.split() for words in phrases]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option, removing also punctuation, just in case:

```
import re

phrases = ['hello! how are you?', 'the book is good!', 'this is amazing!!', 'hey, i am angry']
list_of_list_of_words = [ re.findall(r'\w+', phrase) for phrase in phrases ]

print(list_of_list_of_words)
#=> [['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['the', 'book', 'is', 'good'], ['this', 'is', 'amazing'], ['hey', 'i', 'am', 'angry']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use `map` with `str.split`:

```
phrases = ['hello how are you', 'the book is good', 'this is amazing', 'i am angry']

splittedPhrases = list(map(str.split,phrases))

print(splittedPhrases)
```

Output:

```
[['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['the', 'book', 'is', 'good'], ['this', 'is', 'amazing'], ['i', 'am', 'angry']]
```